# how to pass access token in a http request with flutter?

Tags: flutter, facebook-marketing-api

i would like to create a campaign using marketing API, here is the Curl code, i want to transform into an http post request: 
[image]

AND MY HTTP REQUEST with the model class

```
Future<Campaign> createCampaign(String name,String objective,String 
status) async {
final http.Response response = await http.post(
'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/campaigns',
 headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic },
 body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
  'name': name,
  'objective': objective,
  'status': status
}),
);

if (response.statusCode == 201) {
return Campaign.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
} else {
throw Exception('Failed to create Campaign.');
} 
}

class Campaign {
final String name;
final String objective;
final String status;
final Map <String,dynamic> special_ad_categories;
final Map<String,dynamic> access_token;



Campaign({this.name,this.objective,this.status,this.special_ad_categories,
this.access_token});

factory Campaign.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Campaign(
  name: json['name'],
   objective: json['objective'],
    status: json['status'],
     special_ad_categories: json['special_ad_categories'],
      access_token: json['access_token'],
 );
}
```

}

Comment: You should post code not pictures of your code it will help others to help you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package. It has API to send form data.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart' as dio;

const AD_ACCOUNT_ID = '...';
const ACCESS_TOKEN = '...';

Future<Campaign> createCampaign(String name, String objective, String status, String categories) async {
  try {
    final formData = dio.FormData.fromMap({
      'name': name,
      'objective': objective,
      'status': status,
      'special_ad_categories': categories,
      'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN
    });

    final response = await dio.Dio().post(
      'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_$AD_ACCOUNT_ID/campaigns', 
      data: formData,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.created) {
      return Campaign.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create Campaign.');
    }
  } on dio.DioError {
    throw Exception('Failed to create Campaign.');
  }
}

// example of calling: createCampaign('test', 'LINK_CLICKS', 'PAUSED', 'NONE');
```

Don't forget to replace `AD_ACCOUNT_ID` and `ACCESS_TOKEN`.

Comment: do i put the access_token in HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader field?

Comment: @RamsesKouam You should send it as a part of form data, according to API (curl -F option is used to emulate form). The header is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: i tried your code but it didn't work and here is the error:  Http status error [400] altough i put the token in the form

Comment: and i have this when i run in debug mode "missing or invalid authentication code"

Comment: @RamsesKouam You can check error message in response to understand what's wrong. *special_ad_categories* value was wrong in my answer. I've edited the answer and tested it myself - it works now.

Comment: @RamsesKouam Glad to hear. Mark the answer as accepted, if it worked for you, please.

Comment: How can we send token with Get Request?

Comment: @Mr.ZeroOne Add `access_token` key to the `queryParameters` like this: `dio.Dio().get('/path', queryParameters: {'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN})`

Answer (score 0):

All parameters are in body. Try like this:

```dart
Future<http.Response> fetchAlbum() {
  return http.post(
    'https://your-url',
    body: {
            'name': name,
            'objective': objective,
            'status': status,
            'special_ad_categories': [],
            'access_token': accessToken,
       },
  );
}
```

Comment: access_token should be in header o in body?

Comment: even there, it doesn't work, i don't it is because the others parameters are not defined (status and special_ad_categories) in the header

Comment: access_token should be in the header

Comment: try again, I change it

Comment: i tried but same thing, it doesn't work, the special_ad_categories isn't important?

Comment: All parameters are in body, and I change it again

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the account id in

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/campaigns'
```